# JDI EventRequestManager max EventRequests

Tags: java, jdi

Hy, i wrote a litte Quick and Dirty Code Coverage analyser for Java SE using JDI.
It sets a Breakpoint for every Location it can find for certain Classes or Packages.

And i now wonder how much EventRequests this class: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/EventRequestManager.html can handle?

I tested it with a little bit above 100 attached EventRequests.
Has anybody archived to get to the limit or knows where the limit is?